# Azure Storage SAS AuthenticationFailed

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a private azure storage container and am trying out azure storage SAS, so that I can upload and download files.
I am able to generate the signature, but it always throws me the Authentication Fail error

> `AuthenticationFailed`
>       Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature. RequestId:a9dce486-0001-0021-23f7-d8f6dc000000
>   Time:2017-05-30T03:45:56.6617677Z
>       Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2017-05-30T03:40:48Z 2017-05-30T03:55:48Z
>   /blob/{myaccount}/{mycontainer}/11e1575f-d3ad-40cc-b1ce-32e24dc20324.jpg
>
> 2016-05-31

This is the code I have which generates a signature for me to use, and returns the full URI to access the file.

```
var accountAndKey = new StorageCredentials("******", "*********************");
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(accountAndKey, true);

var sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
sasConstraints.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5);
sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;


CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("*****");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("11e1575f-d3ad-40cc-b1ce-32e24dc20324.jpg");

var sasBlobToken = blockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

var sas = blockBlob.Uri + sasBlobToken;

return sas;
```

This is the signature it generates

> ?sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=9fUwDWfdtUifv9iZXJKgILEM7Yx1uP3Ku0vrspjWyz8%3D&st=2017-05-30T03%3A40%3A43Z&se=2017-05-30T03%3A55%3A43Z&sp=r

I used the Azure portal to generate the signature and it works fine. I append it and am able to download the file as usual.
This is the signature it generates

> ?sv=2016-05-31&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=r&se=2017-05-30T03:57:25Z&st=2017-05-30T03:52:25Z&spr=https&sig=JOnhkge0QWNdv8sXJjb5GazTo9c34KH1IvZBvcNgjHo%3D

I highly suspect its an issue with the timestamp. Because I can see some differences in the timestamp between what I generate from the code, and what is generated from the portal.

Any ideas is much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**
I updated the code to add one day till expiry and removed the start time, this is the signature now

> ?sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=73m3%2Bj%2BUsFk537vd8a7F%2BdpdON1Pg2RZ1IRynMH4zGA%3D&se=2017-05-31T06%3A12%3A07Z&sp=r

but it still doesnt allow me to download the file. Same error message.

> Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2017-05-31T06:12:07Z /blob/{MyAcc}/{My Container}/11e1575f-d3ad-40cc-b1ce-32e24dc20324.jpg 2016-05-31

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Can you try by removing the start time and increasing the expiry time (say a day) in your code?

Comment: @GauravMantri I edited the code to do the changes, but still no luck

Comment: What's the version of SDK are you using to generate the SAS token?

Comment: @GauravMantri I am using the WindowsAzure.Storage package, version 8.1.3. To test this, I created an entirely new project in .net core version 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also can't reproduced the issue using the code. Here is a method which could generate SAS without using the GetSharedAccessSignature method. Please try it and check whether it can work on your side.

```
private static string GetSharedAccessSignature(
       string accountName,
       string accountkey,
       string blobContainer,
       string blobName,
       DateTimeOffset sharedAccessStartTime,
       DateTimeOffset sharedAccessExpiryTime)
{
    var canonicalNameFormat = $"/blob/{accountName}/{blobContainer}/{blobName}";
    var st = sharedAccessStartTime.UtcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    var se = sharedAccessExpiryTime.UtcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    var sasVersion = "2016-05-31";

    string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}\n{8}\n{9}\n{10}\n{11}\n{12}", new object[]
    {
        "r",
        st,
        se,
        canonicalNameFormat,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        sasVersion,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty
    });

    var sas = GetHash(stringToSign, accountkey);

    var credentials =
        $"?sv={sasVersion}&sr=b&sig={UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(sas)}&st={UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(st)}&se={UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(se)}&sp=r";

    string blobUri = $"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{blobContainer}/{blobName}";
    return blobUri + credentials;
}

private static string GetHash(string stringToSign, string key)
{
    byte[] keyValue = Convert.FromBase64String(key);

    using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyValue))
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the code, but it is still giving me the same error..
I even tried [this SAS tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-sas-getting-started), which work on local storage emulator, fails when using the signature generated

Comment: Please double check the storage account name and the account key which are used to generate SAS are right? Is the account key expired? Were you incorrectly use account connection string instead of account key? Since the generating SAS operating is run on local side. It will not validate the account name and account key if they are not valid.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, yes you are right about the wrong account key. I assumed that it was alright because I was able to get the blob clients, containers and blob references successfully. I had no idea everything was done locally... Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If your issue has been solved, please mark my reply as answer. A thread which has been marked will be easily searched. It will help others who encounter similar issues.