# How to extract Connection String and File Service SAS URL from Azure PowerShell/ Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am working on Powershell script that could extract Azure Storage Container details which includes SAS Token, Connection String, Expiry dates and File Service SAS URL. But I don't see any command to extract those details other than the SAS Token creation.

Could you please suggest the ways to extract those details through powershell or Azure Cli?

[image]

Comment: Could you please confirm if you want to retrive the sas token creation date ,Other then that you are getting all the details.

Comment: Could you please provide the command that you have tried so far

Comment: Have you checked the Az modules for related commands? [Az storage docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-7.4.0#storage)

Comment: For SAS token creation I used below command                                                                    New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service File -ResourceType Container -Permission "rwdl" -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddDays(7) -Context $StorageContext

Comment: @Todd, Yes I gone through the Az storage docs link. I have found the command to create SAS Token but not for the Connection String and File Service SAS URL. As reffered in the screen shot I would like have All 3 ( SAS Token, Connection String and File Service SAS URL) through Power Shell Commands. I could get the SAS Token with New-AzStorageAccountSASToken, Now I need other 2. So looking for the Power Shell command to get those.

Comment: If the features haven't yet made their way into the Az modules, you may find what you need in the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api). You can use `Invoke-AzRestMethod`, `Get-AzResource`, etc., to interact with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***AFAIK***,***Using `New-AzStorageAccountSASToken` while we generate storage account sas token, will get the output of sas token only not connection string and blob service uri etc***.

This provide the following parameter:

```
New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken
   -Service <SharedAccessAccountServices>
   -ResourceType <SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes>
   [-Permission <String>]
   [-Protocol <SharedAccessProtocol>]
   [-IPAddressOrRange <String>]
   [-StartTime <DateTime>]
   [-ExpiryTime <DateTime>]
   [-Context <IStorageContext>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

As shown below:

[image]

***To extract the connection string of our storage account we can use the below cmd  :***

```
az storage account show-connection-string --name MySA --resource-group MyRG --subscription MySubscription
```

[image]

***To extract the blob service url we can use the below cmd*** :

```
 az storage blob generate-sas -c containername -n myfile.json --permissions r --expiry 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z --full-uri
```

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENT|az storage account***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest)
- [***SO THREAD|Azure Storage Account generate SAS Token, not an SAS URI***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531287/azure-storage-account-generate-sas-token-not-an-sas-uri)